# breeze: breeze.angular.js and breeze.savequeuing.js

Tags: breeze

I am using breeze with angular.
I have upgrade breeze to 1.4.11 and install breeze.angular.js.

> - The beginnings of a "breeze service" that tells Breeze to
> - - use $q for its promises rather than Q.js
> - - use $http for AJAX calls.
> - - Consequently Breeze no longer requires the jQuery or the Q.js libraries
> - although non-Breeze code in your app may require either or both.

My problem is that I am still using breeze.savequeuing.js which requires window.Q.
Is there any official solution for this scenario or I have to manually change breeze.savequeuing.js?
It is simple. I can use HACK from angular.breeze.js breeze.Q is $q

Answer (score 1):

We do not yet have an Angular version of *breeze.savequeuing*. It's on my backlog but way down the list as I try to discourage folks from getting in a situation where it is needed.

You are welcome to write one and contribute it. I recommend writing it as a real ng service rather than a simple Q-for-$q hack. If you like I'll look it over and give you my thoughts.

All the best.

Comment: So if someone is saving just one entity record at the same time he would not need savequeue correct?

Comment: That is correct. The real danger is during an insert when store-generated IDs are involved.

Comment: Well, we decided to not use savequeuing in our project and will keep an eye on parallel saveing.

Comment: I don't mean to be so harsh. But I agree with your decision :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you mention "discouraging folks ..." I have to mention that the Breeze Todo Sample makes use of breeze.savequeuing.js:

```
 <!-- 3rd party libraries -->
 <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Q is needed by breeze.savequeuing, not by Breeze-->
 <script src="Scripts/q.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/breeze.debug.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/breeze.angular.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/breeze.savequeuing.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/toastr.js"></script>
```

Perhaps you may use this sample to show everyone to show how not to get into the situation where savequeuing.js is needed :-)

Comment: Our other samples don't run this risk. The Todo samples imitate the experience defined by the canonical Todo samples that were *de rigueur* for framework demos. I've always despaired of that totally phony design but *you can't fight city hall*.